# Raspberry Pi 4 19.10 64 bit no sound

Tags: sound, hdmi, 19.10, raspberrypi

Trying 19.10 for a video streaming device.  19.10 image downloaded yesterday, updated to current patches.

When I go to the Settings->Sound all I have for sound output is Dummy Device.  How do I enable HDMI sound output?  Early model Pi 4 with 4gb ram.  HDMI sound works on the Raspian boot sd card.

Answer (score 0):

install alsa-utils, then itl pick up